# grant remote access of MySQL database from any IP address

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I am aware of this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'yourremotehost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

But then it only allows me to grant a particular IP address to access this remote MySQL database. What if I want it so that any remote host can access this MySQL database? How do I do that? Basically I am making this database public so everyone can access it.

Comment: Before doing this, consider the security implications: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63881/is-it-not-safe-to-open-mysqls-port-to-the-internet

Comment: not every system is a production system. some people need this for development.

Comment: i can access my remote database that is hosted on cpanel form my local machine but from another cpanel it is not accessing. showing me this error. SequelizeConnectionRefusedError

Answer (score 339):

```
TO 'user'@'%'
```

% is a wildcard - you can also do `'%.domain.example'` or `'%.123.123.123'` and things like that if you need.

Comment: @kristopolous There are lots of things that could cause that. This command is about remote access (two different machines). If that's not what you are doing this is not the right command. You still need a correct password and other things.

Comment: You have to use "flush privileges;" for the changes to take effect

Comment: The trick when connecting to a db instance running on the same OS instance (e.g. your development machine), is to pass in the `-h my_machine_name` parameter.  This tricks the client to identify you as `'user'@my_machine_name.example.com`, rather than `'user'@localhost`.  This way you don't need to create and maintain dual accounts and grants for both `localhost` and network access.   And, of course, be sure `mysqld` is bound to `0.0.0.0` vs. `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'remote'@'%' ?

Answer (score 205):

> This content was originally from https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/

Enable Remote Access (Grant)
Home / Tutorials / Mysql / Enable Remote Access (Grant)
If you try to connect to your mysql server from remote machine, and run into error like below, this article is for you.

> ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host ‘1.2.3.4’ is not allowed to connect to this
> MySQL server

Change mysql config

Start with editing mysql config file

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment out following lines.

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

If you do not find skip-networking line, add it and comment out it.

Restart mysql server.

```
~ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Change GRANT privilege

You may be surprised to see even after above change you are not getting remote access or getting access but not able to all databases.

By default, mysql username and password you are using is allowed to access mysql-server locally. So need to update privilege. (if you want to create a separate user for that purpose, you can use `CREATE USER 'USERNAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';`)

Run a command like below to access from all machines. (Replace `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` by your credentials.)

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Run a command like below to give access from specific IP. (Replace `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` by your credentials.)

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You can replace 1.2.3.4 with your IP. You can run above command many times to GRANT access from multiple IPs.

You can also specify a separate `USERNAME` & `PASSWORD` for remote access.

You can check final outcome by:

```
SELECT * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like "'USERNAME'%";
```

Finally, you may also need to run:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Test Connection

From terminal/command-line:

```
mysql -h HOST -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD
```

If you get a mysql shell, don’t forget to run show databases; to check if you have right privileges from remote machines.

Bonus-Tip: Revoke Access

If you accidentally grant access to a user, then better have revoking option handy.

Following will revoke all options for USERNAME from all machines:

```
mysql> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'USERNAME'@'%';
Following will revoke all options for USERNAME from particular IP:

mysql> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4';
Its better to check information_schema.user_privileges table after running REVOKE command.
```

If you see USAGE privilege after running REVOKE command, its fine. It is as good as no privilege at all. I am not sure if it can be revoked.

Answer (score 50):

To be able to connect with your user from any IP address, do the following:

Allow MySQL server to accept remote connections. For this, open the *mysqld.conf* file:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Search for the line starting with "bind-address" and set its value to 0.0.0.0:

```
bind-address                    = 0.0.0.0
```

And finally save the file.

Note: If you’re running MySQL 8+, the `bind-address` directive may not be in the *mysqld.cnf* file by default. In this case, add the directive to the bottom of the file */etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf*.

Now restart the MySQL server, either with [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) or use the older `service` command. This depends on your operating system:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql # for ubuntu
sudo systemctl restart mysqld.service # for debian
```

Finally, MySQL server is now able to accept remote connections.

Now we need to create a user and grant it permission, so we can be able to login with this user remotely.

Connect to MySQL database as root, or any other user with the root privilege.

```
mysql -u root -p # for password based login
sudo mysql -u root # if authentication is done using  auth_socket
```

Now create the desired user in both [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) and '%' wildcard and grant permissions on all DB's as such.

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Then,

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

And finally don't forget to flush privileges

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Note: If you’ve configured a firewall on your database server, you will also need to open port `3306` MySQL’s default port to allow traffic to MySQL.

Comment: sudo systemctl restart mysqld.service is for debian, 
I had to use sudo systemctl restart mysql.service is for ubuntu

Comment: I updated my answer and added mysql restart command for both distro. thanks @ani0904071

Answer (score 39):

Assuming that the above step is completed and MySQL port 3306 is free to be accessed remotely. Don't forget to bind the public IP address in the MySQL configuration file.

For example, on my [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) server, as *root*:

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

In the file, search for the **[mysqld]** section block and add the new bind address. In this example, it is 192.168.0.116. It would look something like this:

```
......
.....
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
bind-address        = 192.168.0.116

.....
......
```

You can remove the [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) (127.0.0.1) binding if you choose, but then you have to specifically give an IP address to access the server on the local machine.

Then the last step is to restart the MySQL server (on Ubuntu):

```
stop mysql

start mysql
```

Or `#/etc/init.d/mysql restart` for other systems.

Now the MySQL database can be accessed remotely by:

```
mysql -u username -h 192.168.0.116 -p
```

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysql reload` should suffice

Comment: I just did this and could not connect to the mysql server remotely. I then tried commenting out the bind-addresses and it worked. I also tried logging into the server with mysql -u<user> -p without specifying the host and it worked, so it appears that "you can remove th localhost(127.0.0.1) binding if you choose, but then you have to specifically give an IP address to access the server on the local machine." is not correct. (ubuntu 12.04 LTS server mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34)

Comment: The `bind-address` directive determines the IP address that the mysql _server_ listens on; _not_ the IP addresses that the server accepts connections from.

Comment: After following every step it doesn't work. I get an error when commenting out `bind-address` either the localhost or the remotehost address. `mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: Is it possible to provide address like abc.abc:1234 instead of 192.168.0.116?

Answer (score 31):

Configuration file changes are required to enable connections via [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

To connect through remote IP addresses, log in as a "root" user and run the below queries in MySQL.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will create a new user that is accessible on *localhost* as well as from remote IPs.

Also, comment the below line from your *my.cnf* file located in */etc/mysql/my.cnf*:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Restart your MySQL server using:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Now you should be able to connect remotely to your MySQL server.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris why do you feel so? The answer clearly gives step by step instruction on how to create a new user in MySQL that allows both localhost and remote access to the DB using that user. Can you plesae explain?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Still have the same error. No matter whether I try it with root or a new user: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)

Comment: I tried a lots of things. Didn't work. But don't know why and how this answer worked. But it worked, that's all I know.

Answer (score 27):

Here is how I got to grant the privileges:

```
GRANT ALL ON yourdatabasename.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY
'yourRootPassword';
```

As noted, `%` is a wildcard and this will allow any IP address to connect to your database. The assumption I make here is when you connect you'll have a user named `root` (which is the default though). Feed in the root password and you are good to go. Note that I don't have any single quotes (`'`) around the user *root*.

Comment: Why is removing the single quotes from the user important? Why does this differ from other answers (and the manual)?

Answer (score 24):

Use this command:

```
GRANT ALL ON yourdatabasename.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourRootPassword';
```

Then:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then comment out the below line in file "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf" (is required!):

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Works for me!

Comment: Very good one. Important the grant. If not, lot of errors for requests like `your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements`

Answer (score 17):

Run the following:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

MySQL client session:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'ipaddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysql root password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Then attempt a connection from the IP address you specified:

```
mysql -h address-of-remove-server -u root -p
```

You should be able to connect.

Answer (score 16):

You can slove the problem of MariaDB via [this command](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/):

## Note:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysql root password';
```

`%` is a wildcard. In this case, it refers to all IP addresses.

Comment: in mysql ,what you need to do is (1).change my.cnf content (2).grant remote user (3) deal with your firewall to listen 3306 port.

Comment: You saved my day. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 10):

To remotely access a database with MySQL server 8:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pswword@123';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'ipadress'
```

Answer (score 5):

- START MYSQL using admin user

  - mysql -u admin-user -p (ENTER PASSWORD ON PROMPT)
- Create a new user:

  - CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; (% -> anyhost)
- Grant Privileges:

  - GRANT SELECT,DELETE,INSERT,UPDATE ON db_name.* TO 'newuser'@'%';
  - FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

If you are running EC2 instance don't forget to add the inbound rules in security group with MYSQL/Aurura.

Answer (score 5):

## Edit File:

/etc/mysql/percona-server.cnf

## Append below code in file.

`[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

## Create user for remote access.

```
$ mysql -u root -p      
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to snippetbucketdotcom@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tejastank';   
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;    
mysql> exit
```

#### All linux server works,

#### For MSWin c:\ Find insatallation location \ file path

Comment: [mysqld] need to add in file, else not work properly

Answer (score 3):

Just create the user to some database like

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database_name>.* TO '<username>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>'`

Then go to

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and change the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

After that you may connect to that database from any IP.

Answer (score 3):

Open your `mysql console` and execute the following command (enter your database name,username and password):

> GRANT ALL ON yourdatabasename.* TO admin@'%' IDENTIFIED BY
>   'yourRootPassword';

Then Execute:

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Open command line and open the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` using any editor with `root privileges`.

For example:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Then comment out the below line:

> bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Restart mysql to reflect the changes using command:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the mysql config file:

*Start with editing mysql config file*

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

add:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

what worked for on Ubuntu is granting all privileges to the user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and setting the bind address in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

then restarting the mysql daemon:

```
service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to this directory "**/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d**" then
edit this file " **mysqld.cnf**"

> $nano mysqld.cnf

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

mysqlx-bind-address     = 127.0.0.1
```

**edit to**

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

mysqlx-bind-address     = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In website panels, like [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel), you may add a single `%` (percentage sign) in allowed hostnames to access your MySQL database.

By adding a single `%`, you can access your database from any IP address or website even from desktop applications.

Comment: please don't refer to a thing like cPanel when a straight query is presented, this will never show a working result for anyone else

Comment: @TobiasHagenbeek Thank you for your feedback. This method/trick is not invented by me (It's common on internet). But I'm one of the tester of this method and I found it is the easiest and working method that is why I posted it here.

I know there are some security risks in this method which can be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

For example in my CentOS

> sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf

comment out the following lines

> #bind-address           = 127.0.0.1

then

> sudo service mysqld restart

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant remote access of your database from any IP address, run the mysql command and after that run the following command.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*
TO 'root'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'password' 
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are many answers, but they are quite long ones except for the accepted answer, which is quite short and lacks explanation. As I can't edit it, I am adding my answer. Adit asked about:

> making this database public so everyone can access it

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'username'@'remote_host'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Above code grants permissions for a user from a given remote host, you can allow a user to connect from any remote host to MySQL by changing `TO 'username'@'yourremotehost'` to `TO 'username'@'%'`.

So, the corrected query for granting permissions to a user to connect from any remote host is:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'username'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score -11):

You can disable all security by editing file */etc/my.cnf*:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Comment: this removes all password requirements

Comment: **Note that it is not advisable to have this option enabled in a production environment, as this allows anyone to connect without a password!**

Comment: however, this is ideal for a dev environment

Comment: This allows people to hack your database without using a password.

Comment: @DanielJames even for development environment it's a terrible idea