# can i access to mysql database remotely from any ip address ???

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp, lampp

please be aware that this topic [grant remote access of MySQL database from any IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address) 
i cant understand any thing from

My scenario is i have a local network that have a centos linux server the server ip address are : 172.20.17.30 and this server will contain LAMPP and its allow any port to access the server so every one can access the server localhost by going to this ip : 172.20.17.30 and this is working great and i have a software on many other PC's on the same network

This software are scanning images from scanner  and the upload it by ftp to the server and make a record of this image on mysql database using MYSQL connector , My issue is that this software developed on localhost mysql connection but in the deployment for this software it will be non localhost connection   . and i then faced the issue of not being able to connect database from outside localhost and the whole resources i can gate are describing how to allow one ip address or more to connect the mysql .

But this solutions are not feet well on my scenario because i cant know how many PC's this software will be installed on

any help will be great from you 
many thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [grant remote access of MySQL database from any IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address)

Comment: first i read this topic and i follow this steps but with no results just when i add the server ip address i get the localhost connection failed and i cant connect by using this data Host : the.ip.address , root , pass so i did post over here , you will find my first paragraph  i said that this topic you pointed dont help

Comment: I doubt that you understood the link.  Did you GRANT permissions to all clients connecting to both localhost and 127.0.0.1?  Maybe you need to read more deeply into MySQL docs for GRANT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. find my.cnf file (location depends on your OS ). open it and make following entry:

bind-address        = 172.20.17.30

Now you can access mysql server from anywhere using following command:

mysql -u username -h 172.20.17.30 -p(ur_password)

If it doesn't work check the following:

Port 3306 is open in Windows Firewall (in case of windows) or iptables (in case of linux)

Are you able to ping 172.20.17.30 from remote PC?

Comment: many thanks ,  i was need to change the port to solve my issue