# web service connection to mysql fails

Tags: mysql, vb.net, web-services

Spent a long time looking for an answer for this one - the web service I posted and which resides on my IIS server (on my computer) fails to make a connection to MYSQL (ADODB connection.open fails) but when I run it from the development environment in the VS2010 (VB.NET) I don't get that problem. Could it be related to the IIS or maybe I didn't publish it well?
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

"fails" doesn't give as much information as an actual error message or stack trace.

My guess is that you didn't GRANT permission to connect from all IP addresses in MySQL.  You may want to read more about GRANT and how to accomplish there.  There's a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address) that tells you how to make it generic, but that is potentially dangerous.