# Can't connect to remote mysql database server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vb.net-2010, remote-access

I can't figure out why i cant access a remote MySQL server in ubuntu inside a VMware. I already have the codes, and it's successfully connecting to my localhost as well as insert, delete and update of data's. But when I make a new connection string with specified IP server address it show an error:

[image]

I can only access the files in that server through SSH and browser (192.168.56.xxx/phpmyadmin).

Here's my code for connection string.

```
 Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
 conn.ConnectionString = "Server=192.168.56.xxx;port=3306;User=root;password=mypassword;Database=prodDB_vb"
 conn.Open()
 MessageBox.Show("Connection to Database has been opened.")
 cmd.Connection = conn
```

I already read a lot of forums about this. But dont understand what they are pointing to.
Also i executed the code:

```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON prodDB_vb TO 'root@*' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGE;
```

The only thing i know is that i cannot find the my.cnf in the server files, but already change my my.ini in my localhost's bind ip address.

```
  #bind-address="127.0.0.1"
```

3306 is listening

[image]

And i have this in my my.cnf

[image]

Why having this error?

[image]
Anyone please help.

Comment: You have misspelt your password. Double check. You should not be using the `root` account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure that MySQL is actually listening on 3306? Run a netstat -tlpn and provide the results. If you don't see 3306 then its probably not.

In my.cnf you should verify that --skip-networking is commented out

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = 65.55.55.2
# skip-networking
```

To locate your [CNF file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/3030434)

Edited:

For example, if your MySQL server IP is 192.162.0.3 then entire block should be look like as follows:

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = 192.168.0.3
# skip-networking
....
..
....
```

- bind-address : IP address to bind to.
- skip-networking : Don’t listen for TCP/IP connections at all. All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets. This option is highly recommended for systems where only local requests are allowed. Since you need to allow remote connection this line should removed from file or put it in comment state.

Then we have to Restart mysql service to take change in effect:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Where do i look that my.cnf? in the server side or in the localhost? i already search in my localhost and i found the my.ini which have the bind-address = "127.0.0.1"..

Comment: wat is the port you are having? to locate the cnf file check the link i have provided.

Comment: in my my.ini i have 3306 for the port.

Comment: have you found the cnf??

Comment: sir im sorry but i think im confused here. i found this my.ini, which has the bind-address = "127.0.0.1", in my localhost/pc im using now. is my.cnf located in pc which i am remoting?

Comment: 192.168.56.xxx is this one binded??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16648724/3030434 check this one to configure your server properly..!! Hope this helps

Comment: http://blog.pocko.org/2008/08/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server/

Comment: check for the edited the local server and your bind address is different

Comment: This was the bind address "bind-address  = 192.168.56.103"

Comment: Do i have to copy your example above?

Comment: no you dont have to copy mine i was just pointing out because in your image of cnf you had different bind address

Comment: what do i have to do now since i can't overwrite it?

Comment: Configure your server by following this steps http://blog.pocko.org/2008/08/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server/

Comment: Can we continue it tom sir? I have to go home now. Thanks for time , see you tom.

Comment: Amar is fine. no need of sir,, take care, bye..!!

Comment: Hi Amar, still there?

Comment: This would cause 'connection refused', not 'access denied'. 'Access denied' proves that the server *is* running.