# Does Zaiper works to connect apps to local mysql database

Tags: mysql, zapier

I am trying to connect Mysql with third party application with Zaiper. does zaiper support access to local Mysql databases?. i tried using `IP: 54.86.9.50` and `port;3306` but i get `504: Gateway Timeout`

Thanks

Comment: seems like you would need to define access host on mysql server.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: @AvinashBabu i did but no luck here is the code `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zapier'@'54.86.9.50' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*31BCD245ACE5C80CD603173AFF3B11A828ED0470' WITH GRANT OPTION;

`

Answer (score 3):

Zapier developer here.

The short answer is no, you can't connect to a local database. That's because if you try to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 in the Zap, that would attempt to connect to a database on *our* server.

If you really wanted, you could send traffic to the IP address of your local router and then have it forward the traffic to your developer machine. Be advised there are some security risks involved with as you are opening up a port for any inbound traffic from the outside world.

Another solution is to snag an RDS instance from Amazon and use that for your Zap.

Comment: Hi, take a look at Ngrok :)