# Accessing MySQL database through JDBC with IP Address

Tags: java, mysql, networking, jdbc, lan

I'm trying to connect MySQL by passing an IP address as a parameter instead of localhost.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");          

try{
     String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.116:3306/db";
     DBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
 }
 catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

The problem is the connection takes 1-2 minutes before showing this error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:   Communications link failure
```

By the way, I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: Post more code. This contains no loop.

Comment: Have you tried to add the port number before the /db part? such as jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.116:3306/db

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It doesn't have a loop. There's something that's causing this issue. And I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Asura Yes, I tried. But It still doesn't work.

Comment: have you looked if the port 3306 is currently being listened to on your computer? its possible the service/listener is not started; but still getting no exception is strange.

Comment: if it takes minutes - it's a network timeout. are you SURE you're on the same network? can you ping the database server? is the firewall on the database server letting you through? can you connect to that mysql server using the command line mysql client?

Comment: @pala_ I'm testing it on the computer where I have my xampp installed. This computer has IP address 192.168.1.116 which is where i installed xampp. How can I ping the database server? Do I have to configure firewall settings? My computer is macbook air OS X yosemite

Comment: mysql may not even be listening on that interface. it may only be listening on 127.0.0.1 -- you need to look at your my.cnf file to see what network(s) the server is listening on

Comment: @pala_ I added bind-address=192.168.1.116 to my.cnf and the CommunicationsException disappeared.

Comment: @pala_ Another problem arises. java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '192.168.1.116' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: you need to grant your user permissions to connect from that host. read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address