# Access denied for user 'user'@'ip-address'

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to access `MYSQL`from remote server. i have 3 db(`db1,db2,db3`).

`db2` & `db3` are in same server, `db1` is in my old server.

Trying to connect `db1` from new server using `mysql_connect('ip','user','pwd')`, But it shows `Access denied for user 'user'@'ip-address'` message.

Both `db1,db2` are connecting the same way.

What is the solution for this? I tried some privilege allocation, but doesn't work.

Comment: in db1, you have to allow your new server ip to connect with this user, your db1 may be configured to only allow "use@localhost"...

Comment: Add a wildcard '%' entry for mysql host

Comment: it's look like you put user name incorrect, check it again

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions. They are deprecated. The error message tells you the database server credentials are not setup correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grant remote access of MySQL database from any IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address)

Comment: Problem solved, i forgot to add password in GRANT PRIVILEGES command. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

First give rights on db1 to your user, you can use below command-

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on db1.* to myuser@'my_server_ip' identified by 'my_pass';
```

Note: You can add/delete privileges as per your requirement here my_server_ip means from where you are trying to connect db.

Second thing, as you are trying to connect db1 remotely so also include host ip in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the "Remote Access".

To do it, follow the following steps:

1. locate your my.cnf file and open it:

`vi /etc/my.cnf`

2. after [mysqld] just remove or comment `skip-networking` command.
3. add the following command:

`bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by giving privileges to user@host.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP-ADDRESS' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

`NOTE:Do not avoid "PASSWORD", if your user has set password`