# Unable to connect to MySQL with IP address as host, but can connect with host as localhost and '127.0.0.1'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect the MySQL with IP address as host, However able to connect with host as localhost and '127.0.0.1'.
I tried with

`mysql --host=localhost --user=root --p ******`
`mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --p ******`

For the above I am able to connect with MySQL. However when I tried with the below command not able to connect with.

`mysql --host=internal ip --user=root --p ******`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely (or) https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client?hl=en check these.