# Can't access MySQL from my VM

Tags: mysql

I have a `MYSQL` server running on my `Windows 7` and I need to access it from a `Debian VM` but when I try I get this error :

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (110)
```

I checked in `my.ini` and there is no sign of "bind-address" parameter around so I just can't figure out where the error is.. I can perfectly manage it locally from my Windows. My company is using a proxy but as my VM is on my machine it shouldn't block anything there..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Its not just bind-address, it also depends on the mysql user being used which should have access to other ips not just localhost.

Comment: I always use root user

Comment: First check ping to windows 7 from VM.

Comment: it does not matter if its root or any other user, in mysql there is a db called `mysql` which holds db and users info. If you look at the user table there is a col called `host` that will define if the user is allowed to access from outside IP, similarly in `db` table we have the same. Checkout in google how to set them for outside access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change user host adress as * or given xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP.
Look at here: [grant remote access of MySQL database from any IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address)

Comment: I tried with : GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.dbname TO 'root'@'192.168.%'; but it didn't solve the problem..

Comment: You can try manually edit user table in mysql database and flush privilages.

Comment: I could totally do that but what do I want to manually edit in that table ? Everything seems absolutely right to me..

Answer (score 0):

You should check that:

- "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" is present in your my.cnf
- The user your are using has remote access (not just 'locahost')
- Check that MySQL port (usually 3306) is opened if you have a firewall running

I would really advice to create a specific user for remote access with limited rights.

Comment: Why to open Port 3306  on VM. MySQL server is running on windows 7

Comment: Ooops, sorry I misread and was thinking that the server was on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

To access MySQL from outside. you should enable MySQL remote access .

1- Comment out following lines in Mysql Config(my.cnf/my.ini(for windows))

`#bind-address= 127.0.0.1` (if not exist add it and then comment out)

`#skip-networking`

2- Save the file and restart Mysql server

3- Update GRANT privilege

By default, mysql username and password you are using is allowed to access mysql-server locally. So need to update privilege.

**Run following query to update privilege**

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Change the 'USERNAME' to your Database user and 'PASSWORD' to User Password

Comment: I now added the 2 commented parameters in my.ini (don't find my.cnf) and restarted the server, I have all the grant options possible for user root but still get the same error..

Comment: I tried what you and @mkysoft suggested, meaning `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.dbname TO 'root'@'192.168.%';`

Comment: Try out this :`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;` Make sure you update the password in query

Comment: That's pretty much the same as what I just did as I don't have a password for user root.....

Comment: Try to open port 3306 in your windows machine.

Comment: Well, besides granting privileges and updating config. I'm out of ideas and I have to get going.. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I uninstalled everything and trieed again and it worked so now I close this ticket for good.

Thanks to those who have tried to help me !