# Remote Access to MySQL in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have install mysql server on Ubuntu and it is working fine locally. But I want to have a remote access by using "Navicat for MySQL". Can you please help me to provide step by step toward how to make it work?

Really appreciate you help
Thanks,

Comment: Mysql port forwarding should be enabled .

Comment: Can you please clarify with this? I'm not really understand. Thanks so much

Comment: I dont know about Navicat but did you try `mysql -h yourip -u username -p`? Also you need to grant privileges to others if you're providing access to other users. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: first you need to enable portforwarding on your home router to be able to access your ubuntu server remotely from outside network please read more about Port Forwarding and how to from here http://portforward.com/help/portforwarding.htm .