# Backing up mysql database on another computer

Tags: php, mysql

Good day!

I have a simple php code that will export a database

```
exec("E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost accounts > E:\database_backup\backup.sql");
```

This code works but I'm accessing the application on another computer locally via ip like (`192.168.1.32/filename/backup.php`) so it's not saving.

How can I make it work locally? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grant remote access of MySQL database from any IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify database IP in your mysqldump command and you also need to define required grant privileges in DB ( root@anothercomputerIP)