# Connect to database in wampserver from another pc in LAN

Tags: php, wamp

I have setup svn server. The project files can be shared. But i would like to keep all the database in server pc and share those database with other pc in LAN. I have gone through various forums and still didnt get my solution.

Phpmyadmin can be accessed using ip address. But when try to connect to the database from server pc it says Host "user-pc" is not allowed to connect to this Mysql server.

I would really appreciate if any one could help me out.

Comment: I don't see the connection to the `svn` server here, but the MySQL connection refusal sounds like you forgot to set the correct connection permissions _inside_ the MySQL server. Please see the MySQL documentation for how the permissions work and are modified.

Comment: Hi, @arkascha, Thank you for the response. svn server was just to clear up the scenario. I have made the user with all the permissions provided. Database connections are fine with the server pc. But when i try to connect to database (stored in server pc) from another pc (with all project files located). The connection fails!

Comment: You need to specify which hosts the users can connect from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: The MySQL database server allows a fine grained tuning of access permissions. If you read the documentation as I suggested you will see that the tuning also takes into consideration from where the connection is attempted...