# Can't connect to Remote MySQL Server (10061)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Localhost connection is enabled in MySQL.

But Remote(My laptop) access is disabled

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on "host" (10061)`.
```

My port always open 3306.

Here is my config file (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) :

```
#bind-address 0.0.0.0
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

And MySQL status is :

```
mysql start/running, process 15204
```

Comment: Are you connecting mysql server remotely ?

Comment: This is my error message. here `Can't connect to MySQL server on "host" (10061)`. Yes i am connecting mysql server remotely.

Comment: Permit to your user for your ip.Take a look `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To allow remote access to MySQL, you have to comment out bind-address (you did) and skip-networking in the configuration file.

Next, you have to make sure the user is allowed remote access. Check your user with this:

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

If your user here has '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost' listed as host, you don't have remote access.

Change this with:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET HOST='%' WHERE User='__here_your_username';
```

Flush privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The '%' is a wildcard for 'all hosts'.

Comment: I am Update 'localhost' to `%`.. and Flush privileges. But still access is disabled

Comment: Did you comment out both bind-address and skip-networking? What error are you getting back when you try to connect with the MySQL server from the terminal (remotely)? mysql -h host -u username -p

Comment: Yes. I am comment out `bind-address` and `skip-networking`. If i Connection Method SSH(On remote MySQL server) enabled.. But My Laptop to request is disabled.  Here is my command line :  "mysql -u NICKNAME -h HOST -p" then always output "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'HOST' (111)
" Thanks..

Comment: Trying `HOST`...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Then your port 3306 is blocked by the firewall. :)

Comment: Really? Blocked by the firewall?? How can i disabled my firewall? I am using ubuntu(`Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`) on AWS

Comment: I'm only using Fedora and CentOS myself, so I can't help you with that, but here is a useful link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Oh, btw.. if you're using AWS, you will need to open the port in the security group as well. That might probably be it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: After creating or updating the user, we might have to restart MySQL server if it does not take effect immediately

Answer (score 31):

To Allow remote access to MySQL installed on a Ubuntu, you will have to access the file at this location:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

There, you comment out the following line: `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

basically to change: `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
to:    `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Now you either restart the computer or just the mySQL service using the follwing command:
`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: This bind-address may also be found in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me.

```
   SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
   UPDATE mysql.user SET HOST='%' WHERE User='root';
   UPDATE mysql.user SET HOST='%' WHERE User='administrator';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then,

```
sudo gedit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Change

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1 to: #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

save the file.
reboot server/restart the MySQL

Answer (score 5):

In my case, installed LAMP stack on Oracle VM of Ubuntu 18.04

Here's my updateto mysql config file: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Before:

```
bind-address          = 127.0.0.1
```

After:

```
# bind-address          = 127.0.0.1
# comment out bind-address to test remote access
```

Ensure your user can access from remote host
    sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter your password, then issue the command

```
mysql> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host         |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+

| newuser          | *9ACA980716AE084BCA56C59D19F3CEB7BB87B139 | mysql_native_password | 192.168.x.x  |
| newuser          | *9ACA980716AE084BCA56C59D19F3CEB7BB87B139 | mysql_native_password | localhost    |

This works for me, good luck.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who is hosting the MySQL on a Raspberry Pi 3 the file you are looking for is in

```
etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

You still need to follow the prior steps like Nesan Mano stated above though by commenting out

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Hopefully this helps someone else from spending as much as time as I did for what appeared to be a missing line.

Answer (score 4):

That bind-address = 127.0.0.1 config option means that your mysql server only accepts connections from the localhost, which is your actual CentOS machine. Make sure to set bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

check that linux firewall is not blocking your connections, as root temporarily disable the firewall:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl is-enabled firewalld
```

also see the output (the status of your network device.):

```
nmcli dev status
```