# Access Denied for User (NodeJS & MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to a database that I have up on my domain. I've created a user called public_guests which can access this database.

I'm using NodeJS to create a connection but I get the following error.

> ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user

The error is followed by my IP address etc.

Here is my code:

```
mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "humadshah.com",
    username: "public_guests",
    password:"hello",
    databse:"my_quotes"
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log("Couldn't connect :(    Error: " + error);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected successfully~!");
    }    
});
```

I've **never** used a database before, so I'm expecting this to be a really stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: I'll buy a beer for anyone that solves this in under an hour

Comment: Your code is irrelevant.  Your password is wrong, your user is not allowed from that IP, or something else.  Also, your MySQL host is open to the **entire world** to connect to.  This isn't great practice.  While you do need proper credentials to get in, it's still likely that a new MySQL vulnerability will be found one day.  Don't open this up so broadly unless you have to.  Finally, if this is your first database, might I suggest PostgreSQL?  Latest version of Postgres supports document style storage as well as columnar, and has many other nice features.

Comment: @Drew Looks like they're using GoDaddy.  GoDaddy sets the default password to something random, so it might take more than an hour.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think, it's not the problem of `Node.js`.

it's  permissions issue which user has at particular IP address,
  and in the error message is stated:

`Access denied for user @some IP`

> So try to give your `root permission` for IP where your `Node.js` instance is running port `xxx.xx.xx.xx`.

Comment: Is there a way I can give permission to all IPs? I want this database to be accessed by anyone from anywhere

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations Yes, that's possible... is that really what you want?  Use `user@%`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, that works. I'm going to only allow users to select the data in the tables, and not alter them in any way. Is there a risk I should be worried about?

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations I guess it depends on what's in those tables, and how sure you really are that you can secure the MySQL server.  At a minimum, it's pretty easy to tie up your server so that nobody else can access data.  Locks and such are really annoying that way.

Comment: Thanks again! Apparently, cPanel doesn't give its admins the GRANT privilege, so its preventing me from giving access to all users :(

Answer (score 1):

Its permission issue only, grant required permission to user it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were two objects of JSON. First was test and second was development but dbPassword were not same. I changed them to one unique password and then it works. That type of problem usually occurs with beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new user from workbench and use it for your nodejs project

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```