# connect to mysql through hostname java jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I want to connect to mysql server through hostname but I have this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Le h?te 'khalil.home' n'est pas authoris? ? se connecter ? ce serveur MySQL"
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

when I connect with localhost, it works
How can I achive that
here is my connection code :

```
    public class MyConnection {

    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://khalil:3306/depottest3";
    private static String user = "root";
    private static String passwd = "";
    private static java.sql.Connection connect;

    public static Connection getInstance() {
        if (connect == null) {
            try {
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return connect;
    }
}
```

Comment: "khalil" doesn't seem like a valid domain name.  Is it khalil.com ?

Comment: you tried by i.p first and then tell the result

Comment: Have your read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address)?

Comment: no, khalil is hostname of my pc which have mysql server