# Want to connect java Client application with server i'm using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, server, client, communication

I'm newbie with server/client communication. I developed a java application whose database is at MySQL Server localhost. i'm connection with it using Jdbc. Can anyone tell me what i do to connect that application as a client and run MYSql on other computer/server. Guide me to the path. where i communicate multiple client applications with MySQL server.

Comment: You use the machine's ip adress instead of localhost. You also need to make sure your mysql server allows connections from other hosts. And the mysql port (3306) needs to be open (in your router or firewall) to the machines that try to connect to it.

Comment: but what if i don't install mysql on server in development mode. because some where i read that you have to install mysql in development mode to do this tacsk.

Comment: What is development mode? You simply install mysql on a server and connect to it using the server's ip address.

Comment: look into this same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address