# Why I can't connect remote MySQL database with terminal?

Tags: mysql, command-line, remote-access, remote-server

I've created a database using phpmyadmin. Now I'm trying to connect that database using terminal with the following command :

```
mysql -h server.com -u xyz -p
```

but after giving password. It's returning the following error :

```
ERROR 1045(28000) : Access denied for user 'database_name'@' IP ADDRESS' (using password : yes)
```

I've contacted with my hosting provider. They suggested me to white list my IP address from CPanel. I've already done that. But still I'm getting this error.

How can I overcome this issue and connect to a database to a remote server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grant remote access of MySQL database from any IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address)

Comment: Does `...........` contain a user and host combination that exists in your user list?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for pointing that, I've made necessary edits. Hope that'll help you to understand the issue.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: Well, you need to grant permissions to either `database_name@IP ADDRESS` or `database_name@%`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, then how should I write the command : "mysql -h .... -u database name@IP -p"

Comment: You need to grant access from whatever administration tool you have, not fake the authentication data.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález should I grant access from phpmyadmin? I've created the database from there.

Comment: I've connected successfully. I was giving the wrong IP address :(