# Connecting to a MySQL db created in an Ubuntu AWS instance

Tags: php, mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

Ok so I created an ubuntu instance from AWS and downloaded LAMP on it as you would in a regular Ubuntu OS. When I try to connect to the db from my php script it's rejecting the connection. saying "Connection failed: Connection refused".   So I guess my question is this:  Does amazon not allow you to connect to a db without using their RDS database service or am I putting something wrong here? (I've hidden some of the data for security purposes, the ... are numbers of my instance). When I put "ec2-34-...-..-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com" into the browser the apache message comes up so I don't see why this is not working as a server name?

```
$servername = "ec2-34-...-..-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com";

$username = "root";

$password = “hidden"; 

$dbname = "questions87";


// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {

  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}
```

Comment: Have you opened the port 3306 in the AWS security group?

Comment: No I tried to add port 3306 to the connection in the srcipt but not in the security group.  That is probably the problem.  Let me try this and get back with you.  Thank you.

Comment: what type would that be?  when I googled it it says tcp/upd but when I choose that type it only allows port 53?

Comment: Never mind I found it.  Going to test it now

Comment: @nacho connection is still failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your EC2 Security Group Inbound Rules related with 3306, you can find that on the AWS FAQ. Then, you need to be sure that your user@YOURIP have all permissions on your MySQL database. For your Inbound Rules it is recommended to use a Custom Rule to your IP, not All Traffic.

Reference and further reading:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: Hey Thanks!  I'm out right now but when I get back I'll try it.

Comment: so i've opened the ports I've created a user  and password and granted all permissions and then when I try to log in to mysql I get this "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user..."  I guess I just have to learn how to use RDS although I don't know why AWS would force you to do this...?

Comment: So, at least you are connecting! Now, it might be that you need to grant on user@YOURIP, and there is nothing more about AWS to worry about, it is just your RDS. Take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: thanks.  I think that's the answer but now when I try to grant access it says cant find matching row in the user table.  What a headache! haha but I'm giving you the answer because you did help and I appreciate it.  I'll figure it out.  I don't want to use RDS because I'll have to pay.  Cheers!

Comment: Remote access it is always a problem at the beginning, but then you will got it working! Good luck!

Comment: I got it working on creating a user and granting permissions!  the % worked!  one last question. for connecting now is this right: "$servername = "ec2-34-...-..-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com";  or do I have to add anything else?

Comment: I guess you need to use your EC2 PUBLIC IP, server=<EC2-PUBLIC-IP>, then you can connect your machine to your EC2 instance, I've never used the EC2 public DNS, just the PUBLIC IP.

Comment: yea ok I'll keep messing with it.  Thanks!