# Can't access mysql server which is on a Centos 7, from remote computer, using SSH?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, magento, ssh

I can access the linux server via SSH and I installed a version of Magento, and I know the mysql credentials, so the magento works fine. I need however to access the database on this server from my remote machine. I try using the SSH access externally, so from Sequel Pro I am getting this error message: `MySQL said: Access denied for user 'vlado0'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)`
and same way from MySQLWorkbench, I get an error message `Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable macs)`. So, I am not able to get to the database externaly, even though I have the SSH access to it. What do I have to set more to be able to access the DB on the linux? I don't want, however, everyone to be able to access it, so I don't want to open the port 3306 to everyone.

Comment: SSH access is not the same as access to the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8348506

Comment: @OptimusCrime when I connect with SSH, I can also connect and do queries to the database from the terminal command line. I want to have an IDE though (like Mysqlworkbench). This is my problem, I can't use the mysqlworkbench or any other IDE of this type, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
'vlado0'@'127.0.0.1
```

Means: User 'vlado0' connecting from '127.0.0.1'. If you're not in the same machine as the SQL server, then you need a user@your_ip or user@% (% means any) account.

So open your SQL server and create an account that matches the route you're going to use.

Comment: I am trying to connect to mysql not directly, but using the SSH.

Comment: for ssh, the answer is the same, you need to check wich IP are allowed to connect using that user

Comment: I thought the IP is 127.0.0.1 when I connect to mysql through SSH.

Comment: I can not open MySQL server, because I don't have access to it. I can only use the command line. Ok, maybe I can try through command line mysql. How do I "create an account that matches the route you're going to use"? What does that mean?

Comment: when you connect in ssh you are doing an ssh tunnel (some sort of vpn if it's easier to understand) so you're still not "localhost". Connect using SSH and use the mysql cli commands to create an account user@% so you can connect remotely

Comment: Thanks! How can I do that?

Comment: in the command line just type `mysql -u -p` and will request your user password, then use `CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';` and the last one is `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'username'@'%';` to let the user access all the db and do whatever it wants

Comment: When I try to create , I get error message:
 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: login as root instead `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: I can't because I don't know the password for mysql root.