# Docker Compose : SpringBoot application with mysql:8

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Below is my docker-compose.yml which composing two docker files :

1. mysql.dockerfile

   ```
   FROM mysql:8  
   ADD DockerImages/mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
   ```
2. springapp.dockerfile

   ```
   FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 <br>
   ADD target/users-mysql.jar users-mysql.jar<br>
   ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]<br>
   CMD ["-jar", "users-mysql.jar"]<br>
   VOLUME /var/lib/spring-cloud/config-repo
   ```
3. docker-compose.yml

   version: '3'

   ```
   services:

     springapp:
       build: 
         context: . 
         dockerfile: springapp.dockerfile
       expose:
         - "8888"
       ports:
         - 8888:8888
       links:
         - mysqldb:mysqldb
       networks:
         - spring-demo-network
       depends_on:
         - mysqldb      
       environment:
         - DATABASE_HOST=mysqldb
         - DATABASE_USER=gl_user
         - DATABASE_PASSWORD=global@123
         - DATABASE_NAME=test_db

     mysqldb:
       build: 
         context: . 
         dockerfile: mysql.dockerfile
       ports:
         - 3306:3306
       container_name : mysql-standalone
       networks:
         - spring-demo-network
       environment:
         MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
         MYSQL_USER: gl_user
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: global@123
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
         MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'         

   networks:
     spring-demo-network:
       driver: bridge
   ```

I am unable to connect to the database its throws multiple errors like 
Error:

- java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '172.18.0.3'
  is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
- Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
  refused)

Comment: Your user in unable to access from other host than localhost. Yo have to enbale this connection, for examle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: @Adam Thanks ! How to do this in docker..??

Comment: @Nitesh, Did you resolve this issue. I am also facing the same