# mysql_real_connect() will not establish connection with a remote db using an actual ip

Tags: c++, mysql

**problem**: mysql_real_connect() will not establish connection with a remote db using an actual ip

**current state**: mysql_real_connect() establishes connection with local database. I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.3, MySQL Workbench 8.0 Version 8.0.13 and Connector.C++ 1.1

```
void test_local_connection()
{
  MYSQL* conn;
  conn = mysql_init(0);
  conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password1", "schema1", 
  3306, NULL, 0);
  if (conn)
    cout << "connection establised" << endl;
  else error("connection failed - check settings");
}
```

**question**: what specific arguments do I need to pass to mysql_real_connect() to establish connection with a remote db? 
Does connection have to be established with root and root password, or can the connection be established 
with my user and my corresponding password?

```
void test_server_connection()
{
  MYSQL* conn;
  conn = mysql_init(0);
  conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "actual.ip.address", "user", "password2", "schema2", 3306, NULL, 0);
  if (conn)
    cout << "connection establised" << endl;
  else error("connection failed - check settings");
```

}

Comment: Your best bet is to find out *why* the connect fails: see [mysql_error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-error.html).

Comment: have a feeling the mysql user won't allow remote IP's or a firewall is blocking the request..

Comment: Eventually fixed problem and answered my question through an earlier post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address