# Nginx reverse proxy with Stream block is not connecting to server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a load balancer for SQL servers using Nginx (On my windows machine). To start with , I am testing, with my local system with port 12345 to another SQL Server.

To do that, I am creating a streat block on main node, and then forwarding in the server, after listening on port 12345.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream{
    server {
        listen     10.20.10.9:12345;
        #TCP traffic will be forwarded to the "stream_backend" upstream group
        proxy_pass SQLSERVERONLAN:1433 ;
        proxy_bind 10.20.10.9:12345;
    } 
}

http {..../No Code for bravity}
```

I start Nginx and there are no error logs.

I checked all ports by `netstat -a`  and it's listening on port 12345.

But when I am using Management studio, not able to connect to the remote server after passing in the credentials.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Getting error, "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server."

Comment: Does nginx logs give anything?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Unfortunately there are no error logs on nginx folder.When I do a netstat , I can see that, I am listening on port 12345

Comment: Try removing `proxy_bind` and see if there is any change

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Tried now. It was not there at the beginning . Removing proxy bind is not making any changes.

Comment: `SQLSERVERONLAN` is it a good hostname? Did you grant permissions for proxy server in your SQL Server? You can always use `wireshark` to sniff communication between proxy and sql server.

Comment: Can you check the logs at mysql server? also check if this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Answer (score -1):

I think the setting is good. Try to login as "your_login_id@SQLSERVERONLAN".
[Reference.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/using-a-tcp-proxy-to-connect-to-sql-database-over-vpn/ba-p/390962)