# Activating remote access on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, remote-access

I am trying to access my MySQL server remotely, I have an old pc as dedicated server running on a different address and I want to try to connect to it remotely from my laptop, how would I do this.

I've tried a lot of options, the the one most commonly found is
`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

I just get a syntax error, near the `IDENTIFIED BY`

but this didn't work, and I can't find any other solutions

Comment: Can you please update your question with the exact syntax error you are getting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: @JonathanWillcock it doesn't specify