# Laravel Docker Container Cannot connect to remote AWS RDS Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, amazon-rds

I'm working with a containerized Laravel app that is supposed to be connecting to a remote rds database, here is a sample .env

```
DB_HOST=xxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_DATABASE=sample
DB_USERNAME=sample
DB_PASSWORD=sample
DB_PORT=3306
DATABASE_DRIVER=mysql
```

The container works as it should but the problem is, it cannot connect to the remote rds database, when I try running composer ie:

```
$ docker exec -ti laravel-php bash
$ composer install
```

I get this error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sample'@'192.168.66.1' (using password: YES)  
                                                                                                        

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

192.168.66.1 as my docker container's ip, I suspect that the db policy is open via @localhost access since my dev ops confirmed that it's open for public connections.

I'm using docker-compose version 2 btw, here's a sample docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:

    sample-server:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: sample.server.docker
        volumes:
            - ../backend:/var/www
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=sample.local
        links:
            - sample-php
        depends_on:
            - sample-php
    sample-php:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: sample.php.docker
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
        links:
            - sample-database
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3306"
            - "DB_HOST=sample-database"
    sample-database:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=samplepassword"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=sample"
        ports:
            - "33081:3306"
    sample-nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: sample-nginx-proxy
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `192.168.66.1` does not look like the IP of a remote system - are you sure the host name is properly resolved?

Comment: It's the ip of my container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following:

**Database is publicly accessible:**
Connecting outside the VPC that the database resides, more specifically accessed over the internet, requires that the database is configured for Public Accessibility. Which you said is already done. As you have an internal IP, and the database does not have a public IP, this is not really required.

**Basic Configuration:**
Check that the database name, and port is set correctly, which I am sure you have done.

**Security Group Inbound Rules:**
This is most likely the case, the database will have one or more [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html). Ensure that the security group is configured to allow inbound access from the client in your case: 192.168.66.1

**Confirm the IP address of the client:**
192.168.66.1 is a strange IP for the container, the first 4 IP Addresses of a VPC Subnet are [reserved](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html).

**Confirm the network routing:**
Confirm that the VPC that contains the client can connect to the database. As the client is running within a docker container ensure that the container can access the database. Easy way to do this is enable ICMP packets on an EC2 instance in the database subnet, and check you can Ping it or use the VPC route [analyser](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-insights-analyzes-reachability-and-visibility-in-vpcs/).

**Check the database user rights:**
Can the database user connect for any address not [localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address).

**Security on the VPC:**
Check the [ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) of the subnets for both inbound and outbound

UPDATE:
Here is a link from [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.Connecting): Troubleshooting for Amazon RDS.

Comment: Although this does not directly resolve the issue, but going through these steps with our dev-ops, we've identified that it was the `mysql` service in my docker-compose that prevents it from establishing the connection to the remote db, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's a MySql issue, how did you create the user?

If you want to allow access from everywhere just put `%`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sample'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'samplepassword' with grant option;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```